# Deprecated: Function split() is deprecated for nodes

Tags: php, split, deprecated

I am using PHP 5.3 and keep getting the following error for my split() function. I have looked at other feeds for this problem, however none of the answers seem to work.

```
function storeFile() {
$path = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$nodes = split('/', $path);
$this->store('file', $nodes[count($nodes)-1]);
}
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: `split()` is depracated, use `explode()` The [manual page for split()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.split.php) pretty much covers this.

Comment: Can't you simply replace it with `explode()`?

Answer (score 2):

from the manual:

> split() is deprecated as of PHP 5.3.0. preg_split() is the suggested
>   alternative to this function. If you don't require the power of
>   regular expressions, it is faster to use explode(), which doesn't
>   incur the overhead of the regular expression engine.

you can fix your code like this:

```
function storeFile() {
$path = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$nodes = explode('/', $path);
$this->store('file', $nodes[count($nodes)-1]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys! Sorry for the dumb question, new to PHP.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using a deprecated function [`split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php)

> 

split() is deprecated as of PHP 5.3.0. preg_split() is the suggested alternative to this function. If you don't require the power of regular expressions, it is faster to use explode(), which doesn't incur the overhead of the regular expression engine.

So better to change to [`explode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function

```
function storeFile() {
    $path = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    $nodes = explode('/', $path);
    $this->store('file', $nodes[count($nodes)-1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

```
$nodes = explode('/', $path);
```

`split` is deprecated. (see the big red box [on this page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.split.php))